# WCF Only Add Service Reference in Same Project

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service and I am able to create proxies for it if the project in which I am creating the proxies (by adding a service reference) is in the **same** solution as the WCF service.

However, if I try to add a service reference in a project, which is in a different solution to the WCF service (which I do have running), it is unable to find the endpoint.

The are message talks about meta data, but I have added the following behaviour which exposes the metadata

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

The details of the error message are:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8112/LTA/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8112/LTA'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8112/LTA that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? The whole ServiceModel element is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WCFLicenceService.LicenceTrackerService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8112" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="LTS" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFLicenceService.ILicenceTrackerService" />
    <endpoint 
      address="net.tcp://localhost:8113/LTS" 
      binding ="netTcpBinding" 
      contract="WCFLicenceService.ILicenceTrackerService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you had seen, the service reference is created against `http://localhost:8112/LTA/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata` which has to be live. If the Web service project is in the same Sln, VS IDE could do the **trick** for you through launching the service on built-in Web server like IIS Express. If the service project is sitting in another sln, you will have to run the service in another instance of VS IDE.

For large projects, and for those Web services to be consumed by many other projects siting in other VS solutions, it is better not to use the Service Reference approach, rather, you may create a client API for each service. And the client API could be distributed to other .NET projects. For more details about how to create client API and respective benefits, please check 
[WCF for the Real World, Not Hello World](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World)

Comment: I'm not sure if I didn't make it clear, but I did have the service up and running in the other solution. So I am at a loss as to why the client project can't find the service, which is listening at the relevant port at localhost.

Comment: I got the http binding working. ntetcp does not work, even with firewall turned off completely. Thanks for the link to the article. I'll definitely read it.

Comment: can you open http://localhost:8112/LTA/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata or http://localhost:8112/LTA/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/?wsdl in a Web browser when the service is running in IDE? For example, you you run the service in VS IDE 1 with IIS Express, and IDE 2 can not read WSDL from the URL while the Web browser can, I would be very surprised. Nevertheless, I follow the practices suggested in the given link, so I had not gone through your path though in day 1 of WCF programming I did.

Comment: I'm hosting the service in a console application. I can view the metadata if I go to http://localhost:5112 for the http. I still can't create proxies for the nettcpbinding yet. Not sure why. I'll award the answer for the helpful link and good tips.

Comment: so it is clear now. WSDL standards for Web Services Description Language, it is reasonable that nettcpbinding is not providing WSDL with which svcutil or its API create proxy classes, though WCF support various types of services including Web services. And the proxy classes generated could be used in Web related bindings like http bindings, and net tcp binding etc.